# How to get 'nativeEvent' object in panresponder?

Tags: react-native, event-handling

I am doing a reactNative app.
I am trying to do

```
onPanResponderMove: (nativeEvent, gestureState: GestureState) => {
     console.log(nativeEvent);
        },
```

But nothing console.log... Why ?

If I do

```
onPanResponderMove: (nativeEvent, gestureState: GestureState) => {
         console.log(gestureState);
            },
```

It does console.log.

My aim is to get on move locationX and locationY relative to the element.

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState: GestureState) => {

        let object = {};
        object.locationX = event.nativeEvent.locationX;
        object.locationY = event.nativeEvent.locationY;
        object.pageY = event.nativeEvent.pageY;
        object.pageX = event.nativeEvent.pageX;
        object.target = event.nativeEvent.target;

console.log(JSON.stringify(object));

        },
```

Comment: Thanks it is working, but I don't understand why. If I do console.log(event.nativeEvent)... It wouldn't work neither. Any explanation?

Comment: Probably because nativeEvent has some properties that cannot be parsed to be shown on a log. Try logging any property directly. You should have problems logging nativeEvent.touches and nativeEvent.changedTouches